# Can I set frame for UIView after adding subviews to that UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, size, frame

I need UIView with dynamic size (it can containg 1 or 2 labels) and I do something like this:

```
float nextY = 0.0f;
float labelHeight = 20.0f;

UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, nextY, 100.0f, labelHeight)];
label1.text = @"Test 1";
[tempView addSubview:label1];
nextY += labelHeight;    

if (something == YES)
{
    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, nextY, 100.0f, labelHeight)];
    label1.text = @"Test 2";
    [tempView addSubview:label2];
    nextY += labelHeight;
}

tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0.f, nextY);
```

I that ok?

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker to actually just click run than to log in and ask this question?

Comment: well, yes I know it works, but I just want to know if this is _correct_ way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is valid.  If you set the autoresizing mask on the subviews, then when you change the superview's frame, the system will also adjust the frames of the subviews.